# Declaration of function returning a function pointer

Tags: c, function, syntax, function-pointers, declaration

While reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work) article, I came across the following declaration of function pointers. I haven't worked with such declarations, but the way I interpret it is that: the returned value of functionFactory when dereferenced is a function accepting 2 ints and returns an int.

```
int (*functionFactory(int n))(int, int) {
printf("Got parameter %d", n);
int (*functionPtr)(int,int) = &addInt;
return functionPtr;
}
```

I was curious to know whether such a declaration is specific to this case or is there a generic methodology that I have missed.

I mean we normally see declarations like

```
<returnType> funcName(listOfArgs){}
```

This one appears out of league. Could someone please elaborate.

Answer (score 6):

> *we normally see declarations like* `<returnType> funcName(listOfArgs){}`

Yes, but in this case the return type is a pointer to function and this is really one of the possible ways how to define that kind of function:

```
int (*functionFactory(int n))(int, int) {
    ...
}
```

Luckily you are able to create an alias for any type using `typedef` that makes it much simpler:

```
typedef int (*FncPtr)(int,int);

FncPtr functionFactory(int n) {
    printf("Got parameter %d", n);
    FncPtr functionPtr = &addInt;
    return functionPtr;
}
```

which is far easier to read and also easier to understand. And the form of the function prototype is just like you expected it to look like: It is the function called `functionFactory` that takes 1 argument of type `int` and returns `FncPtr` :)

Comment: What is `addInt`?

Answer (score 2):

To declare a function returning a pointer to a function, first write the declaration of the function type to be returned. For example, the type of a function accepting two `int` and returning an `int` is:

```
int function(int, int)
```

Now, make it a pointer to a function by inserting `*`. Since the precedence gets in the way (the parenthesized function parameters will bind more tightly to the identifier than the `*` does), we have to insert parentheses too:

```
int (*function)(int, int)
```

Finally, replace the identifier with the declarator of the factory function. (For this purpose, the declarator is the function identifier and the parameter list.) In this case, we replace `function` with `factory(int)`. This gives:

```
int (*factory(int))(int, int)
```

This declares a function, `factory(int)`, that returns something that fits the spot where `xxx` is in `int (*xxx)(int, int)`. What fits in that spot is a pointer to a function taking two `int` and returning an `int`.